# detailed understanding of netstat -an output on linux

Tags: linux, netstat

I tried to look for a good doc on netstat especially for the options -an but cannot find anything detailed enough.

example 1:

tcp        0    126 android.home:58797      par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net:https ESTABLISHED

what is par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net? it is not a domain name? nslookup returns: Can't find par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net: No answer

example 2:

tcp        0      0 2a01:cb1d:192:e100:f167:9ba7:494f:61fa:45634 par21s03-in-x14.1e100.net:https ESTABLISHED

what is 2a01:cb1d:192:e100:f167:9ba7:494f:61fa:45634?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: understand. will do.

Comment: @jww I've had a good answer from superuser.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

2a01:cb1d:192:e100:f167:9ba7:494f:61fa is a IPv6 address.

45634 is a port number.

par10s34-in-x0e is a hostname.

1e100.net is a domain name.

Comment: why nslookup cannot resolve the hostname or the domain part? How did netstat resolve those names?

Comment: Use 'host' instead of 'nslookup':

    host par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net
    par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4007:817::200e

Use 'whois' for the domain part: whois 1e100.net

Comment: Because 'host' is nicer than 'nslookup' or 'dig' and query A (IPv4) and AAAA (IPv6) records by default.

Comment: Try 'dig par21s03-in-x14.1e100.net AAAA' or 'nslookup -type=AAAA par21s03-in-x14.1e100.net'.